# Fórmula de cálculo do dígito verificador geral

Tags: c#, boleto

Preciso calcular o O dígito verificador geral corresponde à 5ª posição do código de barras,
tenho os seguinte dados.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O dígito verificador será o resultado da subtração: 11 - resto da divisão. Se o resultado da subtração for 0 (zero), 1 (um) ou maior que 9 (nove), o dígito verificador será 1 (um).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você já informou os passos para verificar o dígito. Qual é a sua dúvida?

Comment: Qual é a dúvida? Você tem tudo o que precisa.

Comment: @JéfersonTavares André Ribeiro o DV esperado seria 1 e não o numero 5.

Comment: Cara, mostra o código que tu já tem.

Comment: @JéfersonTavares o erro não está no código funciona blz, ele atribui o peso, faz a somatório, e acha o resto da divisão. O problema está na montagem mesmo. Estou utilizando esse manual https://www.sicredi.com.br/html/para-sua-empresa/recebimentos/cobranca/arquivos/25420_manual_beneficiario_cobranca_cnab_400.pdf

Comment: Se tu não está obtendo o resultado correto, o erro está no código. @FabrícioSimoneAlanaMendes

Comment: @FabrícioSimoneAlanaMendes Na montagem de que? Sem ver seu código ninguém vai conseguir te ajudar.

Comment: @JéfersonTavares o código não cabe aqui

Comment: De qualquer forma, tente ser mais específico na sua questão. Do jeito que está ninguém conseguirá ajudar.

Comment: Meu problema está no calculo do Digito verificador do código de barras. Na 1ª Linha tenho os dados do codigo, na 2º linha tenho o peso, na 3º tenho o restado da multiplicação... Não sei se consigo ser mais explicito que isso.

Comment: O seu código pode ser demasiado para um comentário mas você pode editar a sua pergunta e incluí-lo lá.

Comment: @JéfersonTavares Ok está lá em sima o codigo

Comment: Alguém tem a formulá para calcular o DV do codigo de barras do boleto sicredi

Answer (score 1):

Se você como eu chegou até aqui. Veja como resolvi meu problema.
O dígito verificador geral corresponde à 5a posição do código de barras. O dígito 0 (zero) na 5a posição indicará que o código de barras não possui dígito verificador;
 Atribuir os pesos (de 2 a 9) correspondentes para cada um dos 43 dígitos (exceto o próprio DV) do Código de Barras, começando da direita para a esquerda;
 Multiplicar cada dígito pelo seu peso correspondente. O primeiro dígito da direita para a esquerda por 2, o segundo por 3, e assim sucessivamente até chegar no peso 9, quando recomeça-se com o peso 2;
 Acumular o resultado de cada multiplicação;
 Dividir o resultado da soma por 11 (onze);
 Identificar o resto da divisão;
Meu problema está justamente nessa ultima linha do algorítimo:

```
     //Agora que tenho a soma vamos pegar o resto da divisão por 11
        mod = 11-(soma % 11);
        //Se o resultado da subtração for 0 (zero), 1 (um) ou maior que 9 (nove), o dígito verificador será 1 (um). Senão o DV é o próprio resultado da subtração.
        if (mod == 0 || mod == 1 || mod > 9)
        {
            dv = 1;
        }
        DvGeral = dv;
```

 O dígito verificador será o resultado da subtração: 11 - resto da divisão. Se o resultado da subtração for 0 (zero), 1 (um) ou maior que 9 (nove), o dígito verificador será 1 (um). Senão o DV é o próprio resultado da subtração.
Pero ter ajudado alguém valeu